# SQL select date range between daily intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a database

[image: database image]

It'll update every hour

I want to select **only** the data with a **1 day interval**
ex.

1. Monday
2. Tuesday
3. Wednesday
4. ....

I **don't** want to select all the **data between these intervals**

**I have no clue how to do this**

```
Select * from highscores where ...........
```

Result that I would like to get:

```
id player_id total economy research military date (2017-09-07 (first record of that day)

id player_id total economy research military date (2017-09-08 (first record of that day)

id player_id total economy research military date (2017-09-09 (first record of that day)

id player_id total economy research military date (2017-09-10 (first record of that day)

id player_id total economy research military date (2017-09-11 (first record of that day)

.....
```

Thanks

---

This is the solution:

```
SELECT 
    h.id, h.player_id, h.total, h.economy, h.research, h.military, h.date
FROM 
    highscores h
WHERE 
    h.id = (SELECT hs.id 
            FROM highscores hs
            WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(h.date,"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")) = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(hs.date,"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"))
              AND h.player_id = hs.player_id
            ORDER BY date ASC
            LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: MySQL has the `DAYOFWEEK()` and `WEEKDAY()` functions.

Comment: Could you share an example of the result you'd like to get? It would make the question much easier to understand

Comment: Add several rows of sample table data, and also the expected result. All as formatted text.

Comment: I'm trying this is my first time I'm posting here :)

Comment: every time i read a dutchie/begian question, i hear the accent in my head while reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for a subquery, don't use `select *`

```
SELECT h.id, h.player_id, h.total, h.economy, h.reasearch, h.military, h.date
FROM highscores h
WHERE h.id = (
    SELECT hs.is FROM highscores hs
    WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(h.date,"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")) = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(hs.date,"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"))
    AND h.player_id = hs.player_id
    ORDER BY date ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

With the subquery you select the beginning of the day for each record, 
order by date, oldest first, so beginning of the day and only if the player matches
restrict it to 1 because you only want 1 match